# Smallest interval for which the number of primes in each is non-increasing

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-number-theorem

Consider the intervals $[0, x)$, $[x, 2x)$, $[2x, 3x)$, ... in $\mathbb{Z}$. Let's call this sequence of intervals $I_1$, $I_2$, $I_3$, ...

Let the function $p(I)$ return the number of primes in an interval $I$.

Does there exist an $x \in \mathbb{Z+}$ such that the sequence $p(I_1)$, $p(I_2)$, $p(I_3)$, ... is non-increasing?

If so, what's the smallest such $x$?

Comment: Since there are arbitrarily long prime-free intervals and infinitely many primes, obviously no. .

Comment: Can't be such an $x$: if there were, $p(I_j)$ would be eventually stationary, say equalling $k$. Obviously $k >0$ (since there are infinitely many primes). However, given $N$, there exists an interval of length $N$ containing no primes, so we obtain a contradiction if $N > 3x$.

Comment: I did not see Fedja's comment when I was writing my comment (it took about seven minutes to formulate it, I guess).